# How to add db2 user as SYSADM

Tags: database, db2

I'm new to db2 and currently working with the environment which all the information are lost. The only known information is one user id as db2inst1. I need to grant SYSADM permissions to this user. Root password also didn't know. So how can I do that ? Is it possible way to grant SYSADM permission to db2inst1 user ? I have tried several ways mentioned in the db2 related websites. But still I'm unable to full fill my task.

Thanks !
Manula Thantriwatte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the instance configuration parameter `SYSADM_GROUP` is set, any member of the group specified therein will have the SYSADM authority. If the parameter is not set, members of the primary group of the instance owner user (presumably `db2inst1` in your case) will have the SYSADM authority.

To check the parameter value:

```
db2 get dbm cfg | grep SYSADM_GROUP
```

To set it:

```
db2 update dbm cfg using SYSADM_GROUP whatever
```

You'll need to restart the instance after changing the parameter.